# Getting error when building iOS platform with cordova-cli

Tags: ios, cordova, cordova-ios

Since I've upgraded from Cordova 6.0.0 to the latest version which is 6.4.0 I've been unable to do a successful build.

My process is as follows:

```
cordova platform rm ios
cordova platform add https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios.git
cordova build --buildConfig=build.json ios --device
```

I cannot build to an emulator since one of the plugins in my project doesn't support it.

My build.json file looks as follows:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "iPhone Developer",
      "provisioningProfile": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx", 
      "developmentTeam": "xxxxxxxxxx",
      "packageType": "development"
    }
  }
}
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Check dependencies
Bio-Oil Verify requires a provisioning profile. Select a provisioning profile for the "Debug" build configuration in the project editor.
Code signing is required for product type 'Application' in SDK 'iOS 10.1'
```

As far as my investigation has showed me this is the correct way to build with the latest version of cordova-ios.

My setup is as follows:

```
sw_vers -productVersion(Mac version)   10.12.1
cordova -v                             6.4.0
ios-deploy -V                          1.9.0
cordova platform list                  4.4.0-dev
/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version           Xcode 8.1
```

Could anyone shed some light on what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I only use provisioning profile, try removing all other properties.

```
{
 "ios": {
     "debug": {
         "provisioningProfile": "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxx"
     }
  }
}
```

And if this doesn't work. Open the xcode project that it failed to build (the exact build number and directory will be in the output.

Open the xcode project, you will most likely see the errors (the red flags beside signing) You can tick, allow xcode to automatically sign and this should build from then on.

Comment: That didn't do the trick.  As far as I understand letting xcode automatically sign your app means your build config will be ignored anyway?

Comment: Could you supply me with your build process and the versions you're working with like I showed above please?